# Simple Talend job with tHDFSPut fails with Connection refused

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, talend

I created a Talend job to upload a simple text file (webapp.log, 50 KB) to HDFS using `tHDFSPut`.
The directory and the file are successfully created in HDFS, but somehow I reproducibly get a `Connection refused: no further information` during the upload of the file's contents (see log at the end), so the upload fails (i.e. the created file remains empty).

The HDFS is running inside a Cloudera Quickstart VM. The username in the tHDFSComponent is set to "cloudera" and should work since it's part of the default configuration.

Any suggestions why I get the "Connection refused"?

**What did I try**

- Cloudera Manager says the service `hdfs1` is in good health.
- The NameNode (on default port 50070) is up and running.
- The NameNode reports that the single data node (pre-configured in the Cloudera VM) is live and that the DFS has more than 23 GB remaining space available.
- Uploading the same file inside the VM with `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal` succeeds.

**Setup**

- [Cloudera Quickstart VM for VMware](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products.html?productID=F6mO278Rvo&version=1) running HDFS
- Local machine running Talend Studio, used to execute the job.

**Job log**

The first I/O exception seems to be output into the error console (recognizable by the red font color in the Run view). I edited the log so that the lines of this particular stacktrace can be read all in one piece.

I kept the original log on Pastebin for reference: http://pastebin.com/n3ZtkDLw

```
Starting job Test1 at 10:57 14/10/2013.


[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3762
[statistics] connected
[main           ] Configuration                  WARN  fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
[Thread-4       ] DFSClient                      INFO  Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1026)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:455)
[Thread-4       ] DFSClient                      INFO  Abandoning block BP-780931682-127.0.0.1-1381159027878:blk_-5532547656644348116_1280
[Thread-4       ] DFSClient                      INFO  Excluding datanode 127.0.0.1:50010
Exception in component tHDFSPut_1
java.io.IOException: File /user/cloudera/weblog/webapp.log could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44954)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1747)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1745)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:455)
[Thread-4       ] DFSClient                      WARN  DataStreamer Exception
java.io.IOException: File /user/cloudera/weblog/webapp.log could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44954)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1747)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1745)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:455)
[statistics] disconnected
[Thread-2       ] DFSClient                      ERROR Failed to close file /user/cloudera/weblog/webapp.log
java.io.IOException: File /user/cloudera/weblog/webapp.log could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44954)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1747)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1745)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:455)
Job Test1 ended at 10:58 14/10/2013. [exit code=1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had very similar problem with quickstart cloudera image.
I tried to put file by java api from host machine to guest cloudera quickstart machine.
The problem was that that the virtualbox machine forwards 8020 namenode port from the host to guest machine, but don't forwards 50010 datanode's port to the guest.
Try to add forwarding of 50010 and it will work.

Comment: Can you give hints how to make forwarding under VM?

Comment: port forwarding manual - http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry in hosts file for the IP address of hadoop namenode you are trying to connect and use hostname instead of IP address in HDFS connection parameter.

Place of hosts file in windows is open Win+R and type %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and make an entry of IP followed by hostname.

ex: 192.168.1.1 hostname